# ChildViewController pushes instead of replacing a view in the Parent ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, segue

I have the following setup

http://i.minus.com/j6rhBqXOkRRjl.png

When I touch either of the buttons the content of the respective targetViewController should appear in the white box below the buttons.

This works fine (see my code below), but as soon as I enclose the ParentViewController in a Navigation Controller, the ViewController pushes to the View with the "First" label instead of adding it to the box on the ParentViewController's view.

Both segues are defined as "Custom" so why does the push occur?

This is my code to display the ViewControllers:

```
-(void)swapVC:(UIViewController *)newController{

    if(_currentViewController){
        [_currentViewController removeFromParentViewController];
    }

    [self addChildViewController:newController];
    [self.contentView addSubview:newController.view];

    [newController didMoveToParentViewController:self];    
}


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showFirst"]){

        [self swapVC:segue.destinationViewController];
    } else if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showSecond"]){
        [self swapVC:segue.destinationViewController];        
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried not using segues?  I wouldn't use a segue unless I was completely transitioning from the view calling the segue to the view that is the destination of the segue.  I don't think they are supposed to be used to swap out `childViewcontroller`s.  Try just doing the swap programmatically like you do in `swapVC` and just connect the buttons to `swapVC` with IBAction.

Comment: I prefer segues because they visualize the ViewControllers quite nicely and on the iPad you also have master-detail-style segues and multiple ViewControllers can be displayed at once.

Comment: That is on an iPad and it completely switches out view controllers from the one calling the segue to the destination of the segue.  It is not the same thing that you are trying to do here.  Just leave them in the same place on your storyboard, but don't use the segues, it is not how they are intended to be used.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use a segue. Use the `transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animation:completion` method when you want to switch view controllers. The segue will simply push the view controller on the stack, probably because the custom segue is undefined.

**EDIT:** You can leave the segues in there, but if you perform them, it will push it onto the stack.

Comment: Can you explain why a segue is not appropriate? So if I did implement a custom Segue class would this prevent the ViewController from pushing to the next ViewController?

Comment: A segue is meant to go from one "scene" (or screen) to another, using two different view controllers. View controller containment is different in that sense: you stay on the same screen, since your container view controller isn't changed (except for its content). With iOS 6 you have a few more options, but that's not publicly available and still under NDA.

Answer (score 1):

## Apple's Solution

Use a `UITabBarController` instead of a Navigation Controller. It has this functionality built in!

if thats not an option, keep reading what is below...

## Understanding Navigation Controllers and When to Use Them

A navigation controller maintains a stack ([first in, first out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO)) of viewcontrollers and displays the viewcontroller on the top of the stack. It adds and remove viewcontrollers from this stack with segues that "push" and "pop" the viewcontrollers onto the stack. This is great for when you have a clear screen flow hierarchy, such as UITableView that displays general information, and a UIViewController that displays detailed information about the item that was selected in the UITableView. The UITableView clearly leads you to the detailed viewcontroller in this example.

Try to use Apple's navigation controllers and tabbar controllers whenever possible. They are convenient and well-made. However, when these won't do, we have to handle the transitions ourselves...

In your case, it seems that there is not a clear view flow hierarchy (your parent view holds a view that can change, but your parent view does not "come before" or "go after" your first and second children views), so let's start making our transitions.

---

### A Simple Solution

Thus, we want our view to change, but not by using a navigation controller that pushes views (more accurately it pushes viewcontrollers that have these views) onto its stack. get rid of the segues in the storyboard and the segue method in your code if you are not using a navigation controller (also make your parent view controller the root view. to do this, go into sotryboard, select your parent viewcontroller and use the Utilities toolbar to check the box labeled "is Initial View Controller". make sure the viewcontroller, not the view, is selected if this gives you any issue). the simplest approach would be to use:

```
transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:
```

---

### Instantiating Controllers From Storyboard

You can get your "first" and "second" viewcontrollers by instantiating your two children view controllers in your parent view controller as such:

```
firstVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:firstIdentifier];
secondVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:secondIdentifier];
```

where `firstIdentifier` and `secondIdentifier` are defined in the storyboard. 
(select a viewcontroller in storyboard and then go to the Attributes Inspector tab at the top of Utilities tool bar. the tab looks like a shield/ home plate. define the identifier in the corresponding textfield in the Attributes Inspector. in actual code the identifier is a NSString* e.g. @"My View Controller")

Comment: why was i downvoted? i'm pretty new to stackoverflow so i'd like to know the reason so i don't repeat it in the future...